# How to fix Discord.py not running my asyncio function for a voice command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

In my discord.py bot, I am trying to make a function that runs the code that's nescessary for the bot to join a voice channel, play an audio file, and then leave. I am doing this, so I do not have to copy and paste the same code for every voice command that I want to make. However, I cannot get the function to run.

I have tried playing around with async def and await functions for my function, however it does not seem to work. I am clueless, as when I run my code, I receive no errors.

```
async def voiceCommand(ctx, message, file, time, cmd):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    if channel == None: # If the user who sent the voice command isn't in a voice channel.
        await client.say('You are not in a voice channel, therefore I cannot run this command.')
        return
    else: # If the user is in a voice channel
        print(executed(cmd, message.author))
        voice = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
        server = ctx.message.server
        voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
        player = voice.create_ffmpeg_player(file) # Uses ffmpeg to create a player, however it makes a pop up when it runs.
        player.start()
        time.sleep(float(time))
        await voice_client.disconnect() # Disconnects WingBot from the voice channel.
```

and

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def bigbruh(ctx):
    voiceCommand(ctx, message, 'bigbruh.mp3', '0.5', 'bigbruh')
```

These are the snippets of code I am trying to use to run the function.

Full source code here: https://pastebin.com/bv86jSvk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these few methods to run async function in python

```py
async def print_id():
    print(bot.user.id)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.loop.create_task(print_id()) #this will run the print_id function
    print(bot.user.name)

async def not_me(msg):
    await bot.send_message(msg.message.channel,"You are not me")

async def greet():
    print("Hi")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def me(msg):
    if msg.message.author.id == '123123':
        await bot.say("Hello there") #await is used to run async function inside another async function

    else:
        await not_me(msg)


#To run the async function without it being inside another async function you have to use this method or something similar to it
import asyncio

# asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(the_function_name())
#in this case it's `greet`
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(greet())
```

Comment: I sort of understand what you're saying. However, I'm completely clueless with how I can apply it to my code. Under async def bigbruh(ctx), by using the loop.create_task(), it still doesn't run my voiceCommand function when I call .bigbruh in discord. To test the function, I put a print statement at the top of the voiceCommand function, yet when it's called in discord, nothing happens.

Comment: Just add await before the function name

Comment: Like such? await client.loop.create_task(voiceCommand(ctx, message, 'bigbruh.mp3', '0.5', 'bigbruh')) (This doesn't seem to be working, this is one of the first things I've tried.).

Comment: I've edited the answer, let me know if it answers it.

Comment: This answered it. I looked into using bot.event for my voice commands, and eliminated my bot.command functions. Thank you for going in depth with the bot.event and the bot.command, as it really showed what was wrong in my code.